# Expectation of product of correlated Brownian motions at different time points

Tags: brownian-motion, correlation

Given the information about the correlation of two Brownian motions as $E[dW_1 dW_2] =  \rho dt$ and knowing that $E[W_1(t)W_1(t')] = \min(t,t')$, I want to compute 
$E[W_1(t)W_2(t')]$

I interpret $dW_1 as \int^{t + \Delta t}_t dW_1(s)$ and I also know that $E[(dW_1)^2] = dt$

Can I follow from the correlation property that $E[W_1(t)W_2(t')] = E[W_1(t) \rho W_1(t')] = \rho \min(t,t')$ ?

Thank you and best regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say:
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
  \mathsf{E}\left(W_1(t_1) W_2(t_2)\right) &=& \mathsf{E}\left(\int_0^{t_1} \mathrm{d}W_1(s_1) \int_0^{t_2}\mathrm{d}W_2(s_2)\right) \stackrel{\text{Ito isometry}}{=} \mathsf{E}\left(\int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \rho\,  \mathrm{d}t \right) \\ &=& \int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \rho\,  \mathrm{d}t = \rho \min\left(t_1, t_2\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Thank you ! Could you elaborate some more on how exactly you use the Ito Isometry? I only know this property with regard to the expectation of the squared integral wrt. to a Brownian motion. It is not clear to me how exactly to incorporate the correlation here. I appreciate it !

Comment: @user113685 One uses $$\mathsf{E}\left( \int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \mathrm{d}W_1(s_1) \cdot \int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \mathrm{d}W_2(s_2) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\{ \left(\int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \left(\mathrm{d}W_1(s) + \mathrm{d}W_2(s) \right) \right)^2 - \left(\int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \mathrm{d}W_1(s) \right)^2 - \left(\int_0^{\min(t_1,t_2)} \mathrm{d}W_2(s) \right)^2 \right\} $$ and then use $\mathrm{d}W_1(s) \mathrm{d}W_1(s) = \mathrm{d}W_2(s) \mathrm{d}W_2(s) = \mathrm{d}s$ and $ (\mathrm{d}W_1(s) + \mathrm{d}W_2(s) )^2 = 2 \left(1+\rho\right) \mathrm{d}s$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
The last property that is unclear to me is the equality of
$E \left[ \int^{t_1}_0 dW_1(s_1) \int^{t_2}_0 dW_2(s_2) \right] = E \left[ \int^{min(t_1,t_2)}_0 dW_1(s_1) \int^{min(t_1,t_2)}_0 dW_2(s_2) \right]$


It is intuitive to me that they are only correlated up until the lower of the two upper integral bounds, but is there a theorem to apply here?

Comment: @user113685 Suppose $t_1>t_2$, i.e. $\min(t_1,t_2)=t_2$. Then, $\int_0^{t_1} \mathrm{d}W(s_1) = \int_0^{t_2} \mathrm{d}W(s_1) + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathrm{d}W(s_1)$, but $\mathsf{E}\left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathrm{d}W(s_1) \int_0^{t_2} \mathrm{d}W(s_2)\right) = \mathsf{E}\left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathrm{d}W(s_1)\right) \mathsf{E}\left(\int_0^{t_2} \mathrm{d}W(s_2)\right) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: @Sasha can you explain the last two equalities in your last comment? Why are they independent and why is the product of the last two expectations zero? Im trying to learn stochastic calculus on my own and i still struggle with the very basics.