# Question on correlated geometric brownian motions (stock prices)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

Let $W_i(t)$ and $W_j(t)$ be correlated Brownian motions with $Corr(W_i,W_j) = p$. Suppose $S_i$ and $S_j$ are geometric Brownian motions driven by $W_i$ and $W_j$ such that:
$$
dS_i = \mu_i·S_i·dt + \sigma_i·S_i·dW_i(t) \\
dS_j = \mu_j·S_j·dt + \sigma_j·S_j·dW_j(t)
$$
I understand $$Corr[\log(S_i(t)/S_i(0)),\log(S_j(t)/s_j(0))] = p,$$ but could some please show that $$Corr[\log(S_i(t)/S_i(t-1)),\log(S_j(t)/S_j(t-1))] = p$$ as well? It requires computing expected value of product of Brownian motion at different times, i.e. $$\Bbb E[W_i(t)W_j(t-1)] = p*(t-1),$$ there is a previous post on this but the proof was not clear and I really hope to find this somewhere in a paper or book or a nice proof. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Which post? What is not clear?

Comment: This one is related but not very clear and would appreciate as well if someone can confirm it's solid. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595787/expectation-of-product-of-correlated-brownian-motions-at-different-time-points

Comment: Sasha has also pointed this out in the comment part of that post, which stated the important assumption that the non-overlapping increments are also independent for $W_1, W_2$. With this implicit assumption, we have for $s < t$, $\mathbb{E}[W_i(t)W_j(s)] = \mathbb{E}[(W_i(t) - W_i(s))W_j(s)] + \mathbb{E}[W_i(s)W_j(s)] = \mathbb{E}[W_i(s)W_j(s)] = \rho s $

Comment: Hi GBM, thanks for clarification. In general is it a fair assumption when working with correlated BMs? and is there a way to implement this assumption in matlab since I'm trying to keep the same correlation p.

Comment: Replace $S_i(t)$ and $S_j(t)$ inside the $Corr[]$ operator with the respective solutions of the geometric Brownian motion in the time interval $[t-1,t]$. The rest should be obvious.